# Workflow picklist criteria

Tags: workflow

I have create workflow based on picklist criteria which is First,Second,Third,Zero.The criteria is to update timestamp field when ever the picklist change to First,Second and Third.It successfully work when I change from Zero to First,Second and Third but it wont work if I change from First to Second or anything beside zero.

Is this normal behavior of workflow?
[image]

Comment: post your exact WF criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you selected **created, and every time it's edited** in
>   Evaluation Criteria?

[image]